# Drawing in Google map

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application for iPhone,which allows the user to draw a line or select an area on the map.Please any one guide me to implement this.......

Answer (score 0):

```
Check these links ...
http://spitzkoff.com/craig/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/maplinesandannotations1.zip;'
http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=81
http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=65
```